# How to get Network I/O and Disk I/O through JMX

Tags: java, jmx

I have been working on to get system mertics like CPU, Memory, Network I/O, Disk I/O using JMX.

- For CPU i have used function OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage() and got the load of CPU.
- For Memory i have used functions OperatingSystemMXBean.getTotalPhysicalMemorySize() and OperatingSystemMXBean.getFreePhysicalMemorySize().

Is there any function to get Network I/O and Disk I/O through JMX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most VMs (all?) do not expose that data. You would need to use a library like [sigar](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) (source is at [github](http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home)), that can gather those values and then expose the return values of sigar via JMX.

We are using sigar with success in http://rhq-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found out that SIGAR API will get the System Metrics easily.